# PayPal Error Code #13118 When trying to initiate a payment

Tags: php, magento, paypal

In the following scenario I am getting an error "PayPal gateway has rejected request. Tax  amount is not valid (#13118: Invalid Argument)."

```
Subtotal :$65.39
Discount :-$65.39   
Shipping & Handling (Best Way - Default):$4.99
Grand Total :$4.98
```

I use PayPal Hosted Pro for HK.

Can anyone help with this error? Why is this coming as I am sending 4.98 amount to the PayPal?

Magento: 1.6

**UPDATE:** I am also getting the same error when Shipping & Grand Total are exactly same.

Comment: Shipping & Handling (Best Way - Default):$4.99
Grand Total :$4.98
Both values are different

Comment: @Vikram, Can that be the reason?

Comment: The error message is specifically stating that your tax amount isn't valid, but you're not showing anything here about what you're passing for the tax amount.  Can you post a sample of the full request you're sending?

Comment: @Andrew Angell, It works fine when Subtotal > Discount. And I am not implementing any Tax here

Comment: @DushyantJoshi have any idea about multi currency support on paypal

Comment: @DRAJI have you tried https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Comment: yeah. I think this too is mage coders suppoert team.I have been using http://www.magecoders.com/index.php/paypal-multicurrency-pro.html this extension for multi currency support. Its working good with currencies which are supported by paypal.for other currencies, it returns an error. But i want to convert those currencies which are not supported by paypal, into Base currency(USD). have any idea?

Comment: @DRAJI I think that module does the thing you want as written in description. Other than that I do not have much idea

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Okay yar! Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reply from **PayPal Merchant Technical Services**:

> This is an intended functionality. With PayPal, regardless of the
>   shipping or tax amount, the item amount has to be grater than 0 for
>   the transaction to be processed. So if the product cost is $0 and the
>   postage is :$4.99, it will error out. The product cost has to be
>   greater than zero. Basically, you cannot apply a 100% discount on the
>   total amount.